# Store set of finite values in Postgre array with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a finite set of situations (4) that can be combined together:

```
fragile
long
nothing_above
keep_upright
```

I'm looking for a way to store these in my db (PostgreSQL as it happens).
I tried to create a dedicated type:

```
CREATE TYPE parcel_peculiarity AS ENUM('fragile', 'long', 'nothing_above', 'keep_upright');
```

and store these in an PG array:

```
add_column :parcels, :peculiarity, :parcel_peculiarity, default: [], array: true
```

However when I run this migration, Rails throws at me:

```
TypeError: can't quote Array
```

Maybe I don't have the right approach.

Any help appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite syntax as: -

```
add_column :parcels, :peculiarity, :text, array: true, default: []
```

Or Alternatively: -

1 => Add column  `peculiarity: string`

```
add_column :parcels, :peculiarity, :text
```

2 => Serialize column as array in model that's it

```
class Parcel < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :peculiarity, Array
end
```

Query will be like as: -

```
parcel_obj = Parcel.new
parcel_obj.peculiarity = ['foo', 'bar', 'etc']
parcel_obj.save
```

To get `peculiarity`

```
p = Parcel.find(x)
p.peculiarity
=> ['foo', 'bar', 'etc']
```

Comment: This solution works, but do you know a way to have a constraint in the database for the stored values ?

Comment: you should use `text` instead of `string`, string is a char with limit (255), text is unlimited.

Comment: @LouisPortay Actually i came across same issue once , and got to know that some database doesn't support array type column directly, so it's' better way independent of db(i.e, mysql, postgresql , sqlite..etc)

Comment: @LouisPortay Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you as well as for future SO searchers. :)

Comment: @LouisPortay `add_column :parcels, :peculiarity, :text, array: true, default: []` you can try this also

Comment: @LouisPortay Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.